# How to have python3.6 alongside python3.7 windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install tensorflow onto a Windows PC with Python3.7. However, I'm had errors. From what I can gather this is happening because tensorflow doesn't yet support Python3.7. As a workaround I want to install Python3.6 alongside 3.7 and then install tensorflow to that version. However, I'm new to Windows and
 when I call for Python in the terminal I now have

```
C:\Users\antoi>python
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

How can I have 3.7 as well as we would have been able on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just install python 3.6, add it's binary path to the system path and call it as python3.6 (actually the same way it works in ubuntu). You can also explicitly call it with its full path: `C:\Program Files\Python3.6\bin\python3.6.exe -m pip install tensorflow`.